# Optimization of initialization function

Tags: javascript, optimization

I usually break down the parts of my app into their own modules and files that exist under one global object. For the production code I combine all the files on one master.js file. Because I'm writing the code in different files and don't want to worry about the order they're loaded I check if the global object 'App' exists, and if it doesn't create an empty object to store the module in.

So if I have 10 modules then in the combined file it will run `var App = App || {};` 10 times when it only needs to run once (at the start). My question is, is that a big deal in terms of performance, is it worth going in at the end and removing the unnecessary code? For smaller apps I don't think it's a big deal, but just wondering if this is a bad strategy to use for bigger apps.

```
// module_1.js
var App = App || {};
App.Module_1 = (function(){
    // code
}());

// module_2.js (different file)
var App = App || {};
App.Module_2 = (function(){
    // code
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `var App = App || {}` runs 100 times, you will not notice any difference (only on *very* slow systems), so I'd say: just leave it.

Generally, don't optimize prematurely, look where the real bottlenecks are and optimize those.

BTW, those extra anonymous, self-invoking functions are not necessary: when using

```
App.Module_X = function(){
    // code
};
```

you variables declared using `var` already are within the scope of `App.Module_X`.

Comment: ahh, thanks! yeah I realize now that the self-invoking functions don't really have much to do with this question. Just used to writing them bc I often return objects that I need acces to.